# failed to authenticate cluster nodes using pacemaker on centos7

Tags: high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I am trying to configure two node(node1 and node2 HA cluster using pacemaker on centos 7. I executed below steps on both nodes

`yum install pcs`

`systemctl enable pcsd.service pacemaker.service corosync.service`

`systemctl start pcsd.service`

`passwd hacluster`

After that execute below command on node1

`pcs cluster auth node1 node2`

i am getting below error

> Error: Unable to communicate with node2  Error: Unable to
>   communicate with node1

I have also verified that both nodes are listening on port 2224 and also used `telnet` to verify that both nodes are able to connect to each other on 2224.

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved after using FQDN instead of hostname(node1.demo.in, node2.demo.in). below command worked fine.

```
pcs cluster auth node1.demo.in node2.demo.in
```

Don't know exact cause for this. Any Idea?